# JasperReport renders parameters as null

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have been testing how JasperReport works and so on but I've got a problem when trying to send parameters, they are simply rendered as null (already checked that they aren't null).

Here it is the code so far:

```
    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager
            .compileReport("/home/alvaro93/entorno_luna/report1.jrxml");

    Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parametros.put("variable1", "Test");
    List<Map<String, ?>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, ?>>();
    list.add(parametros);

    JRMapCollectionDataSource dataSource = new  JRMapCollectionDataSource(list);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap(),dataSource);

    JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, new java.io.File("/home/alvaro93/entorno_luna/report1.pdf"));
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
    exporter.exportReport();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are passing empty *Map*: `JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap(),dataSource);` - look at the second parameter (`HashMap()`). You should pass `parametros` object instead of empty *Map*. Javadoc is always helping you: *[JasperFillManager.fillReport](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html#fillReport-net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport-java.util.Map-java.sql.Connection-)*

Comment: Hell, that was way easier than I expected. Thanks for your quick answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters and datasource are not the same.

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parametros, dataSource);
```

In your jrxml you have paramters ex. an id from a table, comming form outside. And a datasource (CSV/SQL/...) as source of a database.